# Razor Page OnLoad Event

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

I am new to Asp.Net. I have a simple site in which I am trying to redirect users to a different domain on page load.
I have created a button to redirect and that is working, but I want to redirect on page load without any user action. Please guide.

```
public IActionResult OnPostRedirectWebSearch()
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is created a [named handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) that will only fire for POST requests, and then only if the name part of the handler ("Redirect") is included in the URL. You should change your method name to `OnGet` if you want it to execute for a simple GET request.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```